# How to include a webpack module from external url?

Tags: webpack

I have two applications, both using webpack.  Each application requires different javascript modules.  For example, `app1` doesn't use react, `app2`does use react.  I'm trying to include the webpack module from `app2` into `app1`. I'm using the `CommonsChunkPlugin` to pull out the webpack runtime from both app1 and app2s main files.  So from app1, I have a page that includes the `init.js` script, the `app1.js` script and then I've included the `app2.js` file via url (i.e. `http://proxy/app2/js/app2.js` via a proxy so there is no cross site issue).

The javascript from `app2` is loaded, but it doesn't seem as though the webpack module is actually being loaded.  None of the required modules from `app2` (i.e. react) are found when it's loaded on the page in app1.

Is there a way to do this?  I basically want it to lazily load `app2` bundle, but webpack doesn't seem to want to go get a file from a url (nor do I want it to get it at build time...).  I have noticed that the init.js script are different because each app has it's own entry points.  It's like I need to specify a lazily loaded entry point or something.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that webpack can [output Libraries](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) that can be used inside other apps.  So, I have changed `app2` to output a library that I then include in `app1` and it works like a charm.  All of the required dependencies can come along with it as well if needed or you can specify them as external.  Here is an example of my webpack config for `app2`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports.getConfig = function (type) {

    var isDev = type === 'development';

    var config = {
        entry: {
            one: "./src/main/javascript/one.js",
            two: "./src/main/javascript/two.js"
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/src/main/webapp/static/js",
            filename: "[name].js",
            library: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"],
            libraryTarget: "umd"
        },
        ...
```

Then in `app1`, I just include script `one.js` in a script tag and it loads up just fine. One note, I had to remove the CommonsChunkPlugin from `app2` as well because the runtime gets prefixed with your library name. So you need it all encompassed in the library to load properly.